# Xdebug not showing output in firefox in php

Tags: php, centos, xdebug

someone told me to install `xdebug` so that i can get colored output with `var_dump` for php.

I installed xdebug from here and edited the ini file

`http://xdebug.org/docs/install`

The output of `php -m`

```
wddx
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug
```

But still my `var_dump` ouput is not colored

Do i need to do something else as well in firefox

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything on any browser since xdebug is working on the server. Although, you have to be sure that you have set things right.

In your php.ini, be sure that html_errors is on.

Below is my xdebug configuration, so you can compare things. But my system may not have the same structure as yours, so check where do you have your zend_extension. I have this configuration in a file called xdebug.ini on /etc/php/apache2-php5/ext/ . You may have the configuration on a separate file, like this, or you can add it to your php.ini, doesn't matter.

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php5.5/lib/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.auto_trace="1"
xdebug.trace_output_dir="/var/log/xdebug"
xdebug.trace_output_name="trace.%s_%t"
xdebug.trace_format="0"
xdebug.trace_options="1"
xdebug.collect_assignments="1"
xdebug.collect_includes="1"
xdebug.collect_params="4"
xdebug.collect_return="0"
xdebug.collect_vars="1"
xdebug.default_enable="1"
xdebug.extended_info="1"
xdebug.manual_url="http://www.php.net"
xdebug.max_nesting_level="100"
xdebug.show_exception_trace="0"
xdebug.show_local_vars="1"
xdebug.show_mem_delta="1"
xdebug.dump.COOKIE=false
xdebug.dump.ENV=false
xdebug.dump.FILES=false
xdebug.dump.GET="NULL"
xdebug.dump.POST="NULL"
xdebug.dump.REQUEST="NULL"
xdebug.dump.SERVER="NULL"
xdebug.dump.SESSION="NULL"
xdebug.dump_globals="1"
xdebug.dump_once="1"
xdebug.dump_undefined="1"
xdebug.pror_enable="0"
xdebug.profiler_enable="1"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/var/log/xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name="%s_%t"
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger="0"
xdebug.profiler_append="0"
xdebug.profiler_aggregate="0"
xdebug.remote_enable="On"
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_mode="req"
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.remote_autostart="0"
xdebug.remote_log=""
xdebug.idekey=""
xdebug.var_display_max_data="16384"
xdebug.var_display_max_depth="10"
xdebug.var_display_max_children="512"
xdebug.max_nesting_level="100"
xdebug.overload_var_dump="1"
xdebug.scream="1"
xdebug.cli_color="1"
xdebug.coverage_enable="1"
```

Of course, remember to restart apache after doing changes on xdebug.ini or php.ini